# setup mediaelementjs.com to autoplay youtube video with specific controls

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to use mediaelement.js to play youtube video.
I need the player to be with only "play/pause" and "fullscreen" controls.
Also, i want to autostart video when page loads.

The video needs to be be able to work cross device.

Can anybody help or post an example?

Comment: Actually the documentation is spotty at best and the autoplay feature of mediaelement.js is bugged with YT flash player... So don't be lazy and check that there is a legitimate reason for the question instead of blasting a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

having an HTML like

```
<video id="video-player" preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1-jFLlHLPw" />
</video>
```

use this js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video-player', {
        features: ['playpause', 'fullscreen'],
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            mediaElement.load();
            mediaElement.play();
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mg0koe2s/)**

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Tried the jsfiddle on my mobile but the autoplay doesn't work. Also, when i pause the video (by clicking on the video, not the pause button) i can't resume it (on mobile). It's resuming for a second and then pause again.

Comment: @user1610208 `autoplay` will never work in mobile, it's meant to be like that to save unwanted bandwidth consumption, does it make sense?

Comment: Ok, what about the pause problem?

Comment: Hi, your code works, when i changed the youtube url to my url it doesn't play on mobile (on PC it's fine).
Here is the page: http://bo.trademasterteam.com/build/build
What can be the reason?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the answer to your question is mobile devices block videos from autoplaying if they have an audio track and/or if they are not muted.  So, to get your video to autoplay, you have to mute it too.